# Where is the extra space coming from around this textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea, padding

I came across a weird problem with my `textarea` where I still have leftover space around my `textarea` even after removing all the styling.

In the example below I removed all the styling from the textarea except for the default `2px padding`. The padding changes to `0px` on active/focus, but you can still see `1px` of space left.

**I tried:**

- giving the container a fixed height and width
- giving the container `padding: 0;`
- giving the textarea the same fixed height and width
- changing the textarea's `outline-offset` to `0`

but to no avail..

**Question**

Where is the extra pixel/space coming from?

**Demo:**

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: steelblue;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px; /* textarea default padding */
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

textarea:focus,
textarea:active {
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: After posting the question I realized it must have been the border, because I tired `border: 0.1px solid red` and it removed the other 0.9px of space, meaning that with a 0px border there would be no space. I always use `*{box-sizing: border:box;}`, I can't believe I didn't come up with that. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `textarea` width is greater the the `container`: 100% + 2px of border + 2px left padding + 2px right padding

So used `box-sizing: border-box;` in `textarea`.

The **box-sizing** property allows us to include the padding and border in an element's total width and height.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: steelblue;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px; /* textarea default padding */
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea:focus,
textarea:active {
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add `box-sizing: border-box;` in `textarea`

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px; /* textarea default padding */
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  box-sizing: border-box; // Added
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `box-sizing: border-box;` in texarea or all element. my recommendation is use in all elements.

> By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an
>   element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element
>   has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height
>   to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen. This
>   means that when you set width and height, you have to adjust the value
>   you give to allow for any border or padding that may be added.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: steelblue;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px; /* textarea default padding */
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

textarea:focus,
textarea:active {
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```